# Ajuda para somar dias em uma data selecionada pelo usuário

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, formulário

Preciso de uma ajuda, tenho um form de reservas de salas, tem como eu aumentar o número de dias de uma data que o usuário selecionou, recebida pelo value do formulário html?

Tipo algo assim.

```js
function myFunction() {

var datainicio = $("#dtini").val();

let d = new Date(); // data atual
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);

var a = d.getFullYear()+"-"+d.getMonth()+"-"+d.getDate();

alert(a);

$('#dtfim').attr('min',a);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="dtini" type="date" min="2021-02-10" onchange="myFunction()">
<input id="dtfim" type="date">
```

Porém nesse caso, somente é printado á data atual + 3, preciso somar com a data selecionada pelo próprio usuário.
Desde já agradeço!

Comment: `let d = new Date(); // data atual`, por que fez isso ao invés de usar a variável `datainicio`?

Comment: Só foi um exemplo, mas já testei com a própria variável, porém não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Mudanças:

1. Se não quer a data atual como referência, não use `new Date()`; ao invés disso, `new Date(datainicio)`.
2. Cuidado que `d.getMonth()` retorna o mês iniciando em 0, enão Janeiro é 0, Fevereiro é 1, etc; por isso precisa adicionar 1 para gerar a data correta.
3. Utilizei `padStart(2, '0')` para garantir que o mês sempre possua 2 caracteres, adicionando o 0 a esquerda, se necessário.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var datainicio = $("#dtini").val();

  const d = new Date(datainicio);

  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);

  const year = d.getFullYear();
  const month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const day = d.getDate();
  
  console.log(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);

  $('#dtfim').attr('min', `${year}-${month}-${day}`);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="dtini" type="date" min="2021-02-10" onchange="myFunction()">
<input id="dtfim" type="date">
```

Comment: Showw, obrigado pela ajuda, fiz um código parecido, porém ao selecionar o dia 28 de janeiro por exemplo, acaba não funcionando..

Answer (score 0):

Ve se isso te ajuda...
Aqui funciona todos os dias do mês, diferente da resposta do colega abaixo.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var datainicio = $("#dtini").val();

  let d = new Date(datainicio);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);

  var dia = String(d.getDate());
  var n = dia.length;
  if(dia.length == 1){
    dia = "0"+dia;
  }
  
  var mes = String(d.getMonth()+1);  
  if(mes.length == 1){
    mes = "0"+mes;
  }

  var a = d.getFullYear()+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
  $('#dtfim').attr('min',a);
}
```

Comment: Por isso ajudaria no problema de usar sempre a data atual como referência ao invés da selecionada?

Comment: Não seja por isso amigão ....@Woss

Comment: Boaaaa, dia do mês funcionando também, obrigado pela ajudaa!